# eqnarray vs align

Tags: align, equations

#### Motivation

I want to include a list of related equations, say, for a proof, in my LaTeX document. As far as I know, I have two good options, `eqnarray` and `align`.

#### Question

What is the difference between `eqnarray` and `align`, and how do I know which I should be using? Or does it matter at all?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Although `eqnarray` may seem to work "well enough", [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/) [Avoid eqnarray!](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/) [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Ehildebr/tex/displays.html)

Two main problems are mentioned in the [doc above](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf):

- `eqnarray` sets horizontal space around the `=` operator that is not consistent with the space set in other environments, such as `\[...\]` or `$$...$$` (it is wider).
- `eqnarray` (also `eqnarray*` !) has an ill-defined equation numbering, which leads to numbering errors on referencing—mostly when using the command `\nonumber`

Use `align` and the rest of the ams environments. See `texdoc amsldoc` ([PDF](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)) or the [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](http://tug.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf) for documentation on how to use them.

Comment: "avoid `eqnarray`" has been updated and published in [tugboat 33:1](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf).  this will be accessible only to tug members until spring 2013, but after that it will be open to anyone.

Comment: Why do we have `eqnarray` then?

Comment: @masu: eqnarray was written before the other (better) environments were written. Now that the better ones exist, there is no longer any reason to use `eqnarray` (unless for some reason you can't use the amsmath ones).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR and I should have thought about backward compatibility.

Comment: The TUGboat article mentioned by Barbara: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf.

Comment: Your answer lacks justification... please elaborate.

Comment: @Paul: I think the three linked justifications are more than enough. (Especially the first one: the entire article by Lars Madsen titled "Avoid eqnarray!".) Yes it would have been better to include some of them in the answer in case the links rot, but on the other hand it's hard to replicate those visual elements from a PDF to this HTML page (would have to take screenshots or something).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285226/is-eqnarray-really-obsolete shows two cases where the use of `align` and friends is at least not obviously better than the use of `eqnarray` (unless you find a better way to use them - then add an answer there).

Comment: @cryingshadow - As you've demonstrated in the linked posting, it is possible to come up cases for which the output of the basic, "out of the box" `align` environment isn't great. The solution in such cases, though, is not to resort to a deprecated and generally inferior method (`eqnarray`). Instead, as the answers to your posting demonstrate, the better solution is to use a method that's more flexible than the basic `align` environment and fully preserves interoperability with important packages such as `hyperref` and `cleveref`.

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote because there's still no justification.   I consider it bad form to post links without explanation (link-only answers are forbidden in some SE sites), and even if the linked pages provide more justification, as it is the answer gives me no clue at all as to why I should avoid `eqnarray`.  Two of the links are to general documentation PDFs; one would have to search through the documents to find answers.  At present, this isn't really an answer imo.  Other people clearly disagree, because they upvoted it; that's their right.

Comment: One more point, now that I am reading "Avoid eqnarray!": You don't have to reproduce the entire document here.  Even a simple summary like "`eqnarray` produces spacing that is inconsistent in these three ways" would be helpful.  Some of the other answers make reference to spacing problems, but no answers here clearly summarize the spacing problems.

Comment: @Mars I agree with you now actually, especially because now I know how to take screenshots and don't consider it very unusual to have images in answers on this site. :-) (But about the links: the first two “avoid eqnarray” are about the specific topic even if the third only makes a mention. The last two general documentation links were only about _how_ to use `align` and the rest of the AMS environments; was that not clear from the second paragraph?)

Comment: You're right ShreevatsaR, "documentation on how to use them" does make that clear.  My fault for not reading carefully.  I don't think screenshots are essential, btw.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR "I think the three linked justifications are more than enough." The current StackExchange policy seems to be to at least incorporate the essence of linked content in order to fight link rot. This answer as it is is just a link only answer. The important part of the linked content should be edited in.

Answer (score 70):

`align` is from `amsmath`, while `eqnarray` is from base LaTeX, so I would expect the former to be better. Some differences:

- `eqnarray` has two alignment points (it's basically just `array` with a default preamble); `align` has one. `x + y &=& z` versus `x + y &= z`
- `eqnarray` changes the spacing at the alignment points depending on different factors; `align` keeps it fixed (which is generally what you want)
- `eqnarray` allows page breaks between lines; `align` doesn't
- `\\ *` is treated the same as `\\*` in `eqnarray`, but won't work in `align` (since `*` shows up commonly in equations)

<sub>(largely from The LaTeX Companion §8.2.1)</sub>

Comment: i consider the first point to be an advantage of eqnarray. how can i simulate this behavior with align? i need it whenever i have operators of different width, e.g. = vs ==. i want = to be centered below ==, not left aligned to it.

Comment: `align` allows page breaks between lines with the *global declaration* `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

Answer (score 35):

Besides the better spacing and the fewer ampersands to type, a big advantage of `align` vs `eqnarray` is that you can include a `\qedhere` at the end of the last line and have the nice CQFD square (also called a “Halmos”) placed at the same height as your last formula, and not underneath.

```
\begin{proof} The proof is a follows: 
\begin{align}
(x+y)^3&=(x+y)(x+y)^2\\
       &=(x+y)(x^2+2xy+y^2)\\
       &=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^3+x^3.\qedhere
\end{align}
\end{proof}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

The `align` environment only works if you use the AMS (American Mathematical Society) packages. If you need to use journal specific document classes or style files, the `align` environment may not be available. (For example, when I needed to use the `iopart` class for submission to an Institute of Physics journal, I had to change all my `align`s to `eqnarray`s for the file to compile.

But unless you are forced to, I generally recommend the `align` environment. [Here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/)'s a good write-up of what the differences are.

Answer (score 13):

If you must use the `eqnarray` environment, there's a package called `eqnarray` (available [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqnarray209)) that at least removes the excessive space around the middle column. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqnarray,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&B,\\
C&=&D,\\
E&=&F
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{align*}
A&=B,\\
C&=D,\\
E&=F
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The package is for LaTeX 2.09, but it might still work.

I notice that, in my example, the `eqnarray*` and `align*` are centered very slightly differently (the `eqnarray*` is less than 1 point to the left of the `align*`). I'm not sure why. If you use `{B,}` and `{D,}` instead of `B,` and `D,` in the `eqnarray*`, the two displays come out centered exactly the same, so I assume that the ending punctuation symbols are causing the problem. (The default `eqnarray*` appears to have the same issue.)

Comment: Does  the package {eqnarray} works with Cleveref? That is one of the biggest drawbacks of {eqnarray} ....